# Busybox date to decode time in a custom format

Tags: bash, date, busybox

Using Customized Linux, so I need to use built in tools, cannot install anything.
Using BusyBox v1.19.4 date applet.

A log line provides me date in a custom format:
"Jun 22 03:49:56 2022"
I want to do some calculations with that datetime so I need that "date" understands that info but as "date" requires datetime in specifs format, it's not working.

"date" help shows (the same in busybox website) that it has the option "-D" as follows:

```
Display time (using +FMT), or set time
.
.
.
        -d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
        -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion
```

My understanding is that using "-D" I would define to "date" the order of the datetime input im providing but I could not make it work.
Like the command below result in error:

```
date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022' -D "+%h %d %H:%m:%S %Y"
date: invalid date 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022'
```

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of "-D" or making any sintax error in FMT?

EDIT:
Looks like busybox is recognizing the datetime format.
I took as that it wouldn't, based on:

```
Recognized TIME formats:
        hh:mm[:ss]
        [YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
        YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
        [[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
```

But issuing the below it worked.

```
date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022'
Wed Jun 22 03:49:56 BRT 2022
```

also

```
date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022' "+%h %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
Jun 22 03:49:56 2022
```

Thanks to dan.

EDIT 2:
I was mixing hh:mm with strptime convention where minutes is %M not %m. Edited above.

Comment: Should that be `%H:%M:%S` instead? `%M` is minutes, `%m` is month.

Comment: Try removing `-D`. Works on busybox `1.33.1`.

Comment: Note that in your most recent update you're (still) mixing up `%M` and `%m`,  causing the time component of the last command to show `03:06:56` and not `03:49:56`.

Comment: @Erwin, according to example from help, %M is month and %m is minute.

Comment: If you mean the `YYYY-MM-DD` and `hh:mm:ss` type patterns, those should not be confused with the `strptime` patterns that the `-D` option or the `+...` pattern use. Check the manual: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @Erwin. Yes, I was mixing things. But even using "date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022' -D "+%h %d %H:%M:%S %Y" I get error "date: invalid date 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022'"

Comment: Thanks @dan. Your tip made me try and it works. Wondering the purpose of -D

Answer (score 1):

You use:

```
date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022' -D "+%h %d %H:%m:%S %Y"
```

but the `-d` argument does not begin with `+` and `%m` is not minutes.

Try:

```
date -d 'Jun 22 03:49:56 2022' -D "%h %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
```

But actually, busybox understands this particular format without using `-D` at all.

Note that `-D` is for telling busybox the format of the **input** date (`-d`), not the format that it should use for **output** (the `+...` argument)